# How do I resolve broken links in gh-pages, (using generator-jekyllized)

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I am using [generator-jekyllized](https://github.com/sondr3/generator-jekyllized) to build my blog and decided to host it on Github pages. After pushing it to gh-pages (to test it out, and get into the git workflow) I found all the links are [broken](http://antonioortiz.github.io/ant_blog/) (They're fine locally). I figured the problem was in the `_config.build.yml` maybe I had to change the [url](https://github.com/antonioOrtiz/ant_blog/commit/034d72c22bdbc2b87e3fd211582f233bf36de455). But that didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **_config.yml** set **baseurl: /ant_blog**.

Call assets with : `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ "/css/styles.css" | prepend: site.baseurl }}">` or `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/css/styles.css">`

Links are like this : `<a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ page.url }}">`

Comment: Thanks David, does that go for js files too? e.g. `<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ site.baseurl }}/assets/javascript/bootstrap.js"></script>`

Comment: Also, those tags go in your actual `default.html` `head,html` files right?

Comment: Use baseurl for all assets (css, js, img). And yes you have to change this everywhere in your site.